# Check if a string startswith any element in a tuple, if True, return that element

Tags: python-3.x, string, startswith

I have a tuple of values as follows:

```
commands = ("time", "weather", "note")
```

I get an input from the user and I check if the input matches any value in the tuple as follows:

```
if user_input.startswith(commands):
    # Do stuff based on the command
```

What I would like to do is exactly as the above, but with the matched item returned. I tried many methods, but nothing really worked. Thank you in advance.

Edit:
At some point I thought I could use the Walrus operator, but you would figure out it wouldn't work.

```
if user_input.startswith(returned_command := commands):
    command = returned_command
    # actually command only gets the commands variable.
```

Comment: Show us what you tried. [mre] ftw.

Comment: I added what I have tried as an attempt so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function takes a function of one argument and a list of arguments, and will return the first argument that makes the function return a truthy value.  Otherwise, it will raise an error:

```
def first_matching(matches, candidates):
    try:
        return next(filter(matches, candidates))
    except StopIteration:
        raise ValueError("No matching candidate")

result = first_matching(user_input.startswith, commands)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You can store your functions inside a dictionary and call them.

```
def print_time():
    print("Time")

def exit_now():
    exit()

def print_something(*args):
    for item in args:
        print(item)

command_dict = {
    "time": print_time,
    "something": print_something,
    "exit": exit_now
}

while True:
    user_input = input("Input command: ")
    command, *args = user_input.split()
    command_dict[command](*args)
```

output:

```
Input command: time
Time
Input command: something 1 2 3
1
2
3
Input command: exit
```

Comment: thank you for your response, but I would like to return the matched element exactly for reasons such as calculate their lengths. for example len(some_returned_command)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `any`.

```
user_input = input()
if any(user_input.startswith(s) for s in commands):
    # The input is valid.
```

If you want to ask for user inputs until their reply is valid, shove that in a while loop.

```
match = None

while True:
    user_input = input()
    if any(user_input.startswith(s) for s in commands): # Make sure there is a match at all. 
       for c in commands:
           if user_input.startswith(c):
               match = c # Find which command matched in particular.
               break     # Exit the loop.
    else:
        print(f"Your selection should be one of {commands}.")


# ...
# Do something with the now valid input and matched element.
# ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I don't see how would that return the matched value? I could already validate if the input matches any element in the tuple, but I'd like to return that element which has been matched.

Comment: Well the element that was matched is equal to `user_input`, i.e. you are sure it's one of `("time", "weather", "note")` after the while loop.

Comment: The user_input doesn't equal the matched elmenet exactly, for example:   while True:
    commands = ("time", "weather", "note")
    user_input = input()
    if any(user_input.startswith(s) for s in commands):
        print(user_input)
        break # The input is valid. 
    else:
        print(f"Your selection should be one of {commands}.")

if I type in 'time abcded', the time element will be matched against the input, as the input startswith('time'), so if I was to take the value of user_input, it would equal the 'time abcded' and not the matched element 'time'

Answer (score 0):

With Python 3.8 or later this should work:

```
if any(user_input.startswith(returned_command := c) for c in commands):
    print(returned_command)
```